# NullPointerException for instance of Console

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

When I execute this code...

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.lang.String;
public class Beginning 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Console pass =  System.console();
        String username = pass.readLine("Enter username here -> "); //line 1
        char password[] = pass.readPassword("Enter password here -> ");
        System.out.println(username);
    }
}
```

... I get the following error - `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` at the line 1 marked in the code. How can I correct this? I have read few other NullPointerException answers but still can't seem to solve my problem. (I'm a beginner, btw)

Comment: 99% sure this is your bug, if not we can reopen this.

Comment: Yes it sure is, should have googled better! Thanks a lot :)